# Isabelle/HOL: What does the THE construct denote?

Tags: isabelle

I saw the construct `THE x. A` in the source code of the Isabelle/HOL standard library. What does this construct denote? It seems to be similar to `SOME x. A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`THE` is a description operator like `SOME`, but with a weaker axiomatization. `THE x. P x` denotes the unique value that satisfies the predicate `P` provided that such a unique value exists. If not, `THE x. P x` is unspecified. It is also known as Russell's description operator. So if you use `THE`, then whenever you want to prove anything non-trivial about `THE x. P x`, you must prove that there is exactly one value satisfying `P`.

With `SOME`, there may be several values that satisfy `P`; `SOME x. P x` then denotes one of them. If there are none, then `SOME x. P x` is also unspecified. It is known as Hilbert's choice operator and essentially gives you the axiom of choice. To prove something non-trivial about `SOME x. P x`, you must show that there is some value satisfying `P`.

In general, `THE` is preferable over `SOME` whenever you can use it, because it relies on a weaker axiom and indicates the uniqueness to the reader.